# Javascript Unit testing dependencies - How to make a test fail when a depended object changes

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, stubbing, sinon

I have a controller which is depended on a model property.
I wrote a test which test this controller and stubbed the model, How can I make my controller test fail whenever the model property name changes?

Here is an example:

Model:

```
function Model(obj){
  this.id = obj.id; 
  this.name = obj.name;
}
```

Controller:

```
function Controller( model ){
  this.model = model
};
Controller.prototype.showName = function() { 
  return this.model.name; 
}
```

Controller test:

```
describe("A controller", function(){

  var controller = new Controller( new Model({id:1, name: "john"}) );

  it ("should show the person name", function(){
    expect(controller.showName).toEqual("john");
  });

});
```

I want this test to fail whenever the "name" property changes to something else, something like "name2".

Anyone got a good suggestion on how to do it in javascript?

Thanks,
Shai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the model is exposed you can check for the existence of the property.

```
expect(controller.name).toBeDefined();
```

On the other hand, this test would fail anyway if the property of the model was renamed and the controller wouldn't be altered too.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up to do that, but it's not exactly what I've aimed for, because I'm working with stubs, I want some behind the scenes mechanism that will assert that the actual property existence, and I could just stub the object.

Comment: Well, you could write your own matcher. `return obj.hasOwnProperty(name);` Or you could do a for in loop to get all the properties from the prototype chain and check if one has the name you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, according to Christian Johansen, you could actually do it with using Sandbox, although I didn't use it yet, I'm gonna check it out.